# What exactly is the term of mass we should use for Newton's second law calculations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

Suppose a small block and using my hand I push it. Let's say the block had some mass $'m'$, and, say this block builds up an acceleration of $a$ when my finger accelerates at a rate of $a'$ and finally let $M$ be the mass of the region of my body which would exert force.

By the third law,

$ ma= Ma'$

But what is $M$? What specific region of my hand should I take the mass of when doing these calculations? For example, how do I choose whether to put the weight of the hand till my writ or the weight of it till my elbow into the formula?

---

Edit: Some answers say that pushing the object will cause a force on the whole body.. but how ? if you a system exerts force in a local region, then how can that cause the whole system to move?

By this logic would I have to account for frictional forces on my feet when I push the spring down?

---

I am not asking for the types of forces like in this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581142/type-of-force-of-m-veca?noredirect=1&lq=1). Very particularly, I am asking for the precise definition of mass which we use in the definition of Newton's second law.

Comment: Why stop at the elbow? Why not make it the entire body ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of force of $m\vec{a}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581142/type-of-force-of-m-veca)

Comment: I really do not understand why you think that post answers my question

Comment: You are using point mechanics for both the object and your body. Presumably the object deforms sufficiently little for this, but your body does deform.

Answer (score 2):

If you are pushing the block with your finger, then the acceleration of the block and your finger are the same.

The equation $ma=Ma'$ holds true only if you're standing on a frictionless floor while pushing the block. In that case, $M$ will be the mass of your entire body, and $a'$ will be the acceleration of your centre of mass. (while your entire body moves backwards, as you are extending your arm to push the block, it will move forward)

However, I don't think that's what you meant in this case. The rate of change of momentum, i.e. $Ma'$ in your case, is equal to the **net** force acting on the body. Presumably you're standing on a normal floor, so friction will provide a sufficient opposite force to provide the slight forward acceleration to your centre of mass (since you are extending your arm forward), while your arm provides the force necessary to accelerate the block.

Comment: So, you're saying If I push down the spring then I'd also have to account for the forces on my feet...? that seems a bit strange

Comment: You can consider any part of your body as long as you consider all the forces on it. For example, if you consider only your forearm you will consider the reaction force from the block, and the muscular force from your upper arm. However, since there are countless forces acting throughout your body in various directions, its very difficult to do this every time, and also pointless in this case. Its much easier to consider your entire body as a system, and analyze the external forces acting on it.

Comment: It really depends on what information you wish to find using the equations. What is your goal here?

Comment: I wish to understand how to choose physical parameters when I do real life experiments

Answer (score 1):

The reaction force from the object you are  pushing is not the only force acting on your hand, arm, or body.  Generally, the static friction force from your floor or chair will adjust itself so that you do not accelerate.

Answer (score 1):

When you push the block you exert a force and an equal and opposite force is exerted on you. But this force is local and hence only local parts accelerate. But here's the catch: Your body parts are connected and hence they resist this relative motion and in doing so apply force on one another, in return to which they themselves experience a force. In similar fashion this force is transmitted throughout your body and causes it to accelerate as a whole.

This is simplified version of the true process but is a working one.

So at last I would say that what this "M" is really depends on how much dynamic information are you trying to get from the system and it will vary from one model to another.

Comment: Hmm I think I sort of get what you are saying but some diagrams would help to understand

Comment: @Burian you can search about biomechanics and get the required answer. For example you can search about say "biomechanics of push ups" or say "biomechanics of Walking " and get the appropriate arcticle /image related to it.