# What exactly is force - apart from "the ability to do work"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, definition

Does force - any kind - have an identity of its own apart from the set of effects it brings about?  Or is it just "that which" ... "causes"; does this and that, makes certain things happen, which did not exist previously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is force? What is its source or origin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647976/)

Comment: Another tautological way to look at force is “that which causes a body to accelerate.”