# Why is force not dependent upon velocity but on acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, velocity, differentiation

Force is not dependent upon velocity but on acceleration but acceleration is dependent upon velocity, What i mean is a=change in velocity/change in time.So in order to calculate acceleration i need velocity which means i indirectly need velocity to calculate force as F=m x a

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are forces that depend upon the velocity: In electromagnetism **F** = q **E** + **v** $\times$ **B**

Comment: In order to calculate velocity, we need to know the positions at different times. Following that type of reasoning, force depends on position, what is not valid in general.

Answer (score 1):

Force and velocity are indeed related to each other, in exactly the way you've already detailed. We using think of Newton's second law in the following form:

$$\sum \vec{F} = m\vec{a}$$

(do notice - it's *the sum of all the forces* that gives you an acceleration, not a single force by itself!)

But, since the acceleration is the derivative of velocity, we can just as easily write Newton's second law as

$$\sum \vec{F}=m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$

Going one step further, that means the velocity as a function of time of an object is the integral (with some initial condition $v(0)$...)

$$\vec{v}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\sum\vec{F}}{m}dt'$$

That's the great thing about the equal sign...as long as we respect it, we can write anything we like!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is force not dependent upon velocity but on acceleration?

If the velocity is constant, there is no force , the velocity can be any size, there will still be no force defined. Only if there is a change in velocity with time it is necessary to define a force to model the kinematics, which force can be written as dp/dt ,the change of momentum in time, i.e. the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is not dependent on velocity, only on the change of velocity. You have no netto acting force if velocity is constant. (maybe you think of a car or bicycle driving with constant speed, you need force to keep the velocity, but the force you need ist against the force of friction, do th sum of forces is zero)

Comment: What i meant was a=change in velocity/change in time.So in order to calculate acceleration i need velocity which means i indirectly need velocity to calculate force as F=m x a

Comment: @AyushSharma You don't need velocity, you only need the change in velocity. If I tell you the object's change in velocity was 10m/s over the course of 10s, that is sufficient to calculate acceleration, regardless of whether that was a change from 0m/s to 10m/s, or 100m/s to 110m/s. In practice you are often given an initial and final velocity and have to calculate the change yourself, but the actual velocities themselves are entirely irrelevant given the change.

Answer (score 0):

You question is predicated on the false assumption that force is dependent upon acceleration, which is not true. This seems to be based on a misunderstanding of what Newton's Second Law is saying. As I explained in [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/581148/195139) to a related question, the $\vec F$ and the $m\vec a$ in $\vec F=m\vec a$ are two different things, which Newton's Second Law tells us are equal. Force is not mass times acceleration, rather it is a measure of how much something is being pushed or pulled.

In addition, it's worth noting that there are forces that are dependent upon velocity, such as air resistance, which is commonly in the form of $F\propto v$ or $F\propto v^2$, and the magnetic force, given by $\vec F=\vec v\times\vec B$, as jim pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's second law is taught in a garbage way. We should state its content more explicitly. What the law explicitly states is that:

$$ma=F(x_i, v_i)$$

This formula is supposed to help you calculate acceleration, and NOT FORCE. This is why I explicitly wrote $F$ as $F(x_i,v_i)$. This means that there is **always** a separate formula to calculate force. This formula generally depends on the positions $x_i$ and velocities $v_i$ of  every body in your system. The separate formulae of gravity and Coulomb force (the $\frac{1}{r^2}$ stuff) only depend on the positions of bodies. The formula of magnetic force depends on positions as well as velocities of the particles.

Answer (score -1):

ok so a in the formula of F=ma is basically average acceleration or a(av) = delta v / delta t and yes you need inital velocity and the last velocity to calculate F but sometimes they will just give you a , and you dont need the velocity or time . the physical reason of why its dependent on a however is a different story . basically in newtons first law we know constant velocity (0 or non 0) means F(net)=0 . btw we actually feel acceleration not velocity . for example if youre in an airplane we constant velocity in the sky you wont feel it unless you look outside but if it starts to land then because of the acceleration you will feel the force. thats the best i can  explain .

Comment: Welcome to SE. Sorry, but I was very confused reading this answer. The first sentence is not correct, $a$ in $F=ma$ is NOT 'basically AVERAGE acceleration'. If the force is constant, the acceleration it causes will be constant. If it is time dependent, the acceleration will be, too.

Comment: yeah you're right  . i meant when the force is constant which is mostly what i dealt with but yes if not then it could be instantenous acceleration .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).